# Airflow 2 - error MySQL server has gone away

Tags: airflow

I am running Airflow with backend mariaDB and periodically when a DAG task is being scheduled, I noticed the following error in airflow worker
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away').
I am not sure if the issue occurres due to misconfiguration of airflow, or it has to do that the backend is mariaDB, which as I saw it is not a recommended database.
Also, in mariaDB logs, I see the following warning repeating almost every minute
[Warning] Aborted connection 305627 to db: 'airflow' user: 'airflow' host: 'hostname' (Got an error reading communication packets)

I've seen some similar issues mentioned, but whatever I tried so far it didn't help.

The question is, Should I change database to MySQL? Or some configuration has to be done in mariaDB's end?

- Airflow v2.0.1
- MariaDB 10.5.5
- SQLAlchemy 1.3.23

Comment: its highly recommended by apache airflow maintainers to use `postgresdb`. MySQL also works fine, but MariaDB requires extra configuration . 

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/set-up-database.html

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say - you need to look for the reason why your DB connection get aborted. MariaDB for quick testing with single scheduler **might** work, but there is some reason why your connection to the DB gets disconnected.

There are few things you can do:

- airflow has `db check` command line command and you can run it to test if the DB configuration is working - maybe the errors that you will see will be obious when you try
- airflow also has another useful command `db shell` - it will allow you to connect to the DB and run sql queries for example. This migh tell you if your connection is "stable". You can connect and run some queries and see if your connection is not interrupted in the meantime
- You can see at more logs and your network connectivity to see if you have problems
- finally check if you have enough resources to run airflow + DB. Ofthen things like that happen when you do not have enough memory for example. Airflow + DB requires at least 4GB RAM minimum from the experience (depends on the DB configuration) and if you are on Mac or Windows and using Docker, Docker VM by default has less memory than that available and you need to increase it.
- look at other resources - disk space, memory, number of connections, etc. all can be your problem.